# iPhone Email Does Not Update After Active Directory Password Change

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, iphone, password-reset

Scenario:

End user is traveling. Uses a laptop, Windows 7 Professional in an active directory environment. Changed their AD Password via VPN. This worked just fine.

Business Email is via Office365. End user uses Outlook 2013 Desktop Client. This works just fine.

End user has an iPhone, but email is now not updating. Settings in iOS look correct:

Server: outlook.office365.com
username: full email address is used
Password: has been entered several times

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: o365 password synced with your AD ?

Comment: Just forced a sync on the Domain Controller from PowerShell: · Import-Module ADSync
· Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta   | It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to force a sync from the Domain Controller to O365 from Powershell (runas admin) using the following commands:

· Import-Module ADSync
· Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta

Results = successful

The end user was then able to get his email successfully.

Thank you.